# Following a nested directory structure until the end

Tags: python, directory

I have a some directories that contain some other directories which, at the lowest level, contain bunch of csv files such as (folder) a -> b -> c -> (csv files). There is usually only one folder at each level. When I process a directory how can I follow this structure until the end to get the csv files ? I was thinking maybe a recursive solution but I think there may be better ways to do this. I am using python. Hope I was clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`os`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) package has a [`walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) function that will do *exactly* what you need:

```
for current_path, directory, files in walk("/some/path"):
    # current_path is the full path of the directory we are currently in
    # directory is the name of the directory
    # files is a list of file names in this directory
```

You can use [`os.path`'s](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) to derive the full path to each file (if you need it).

Alternately, you might find the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module to be of more use to you:

```
for csv_file in glob(/some/path/*/*.csv"):
    # csv_file is the full path to the csv file.
```